# May one roll a Sefer Torah on Friday Yom Tov for Shabbat use?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, yom-tov, eruv-tavshilin

Based on my understanding...

One is not allowed to make preparations on the 1st day of Yom Tov for the 2nd day. An *Eruv Tavshilin* allows one to cook, bake and make food preparations on Friday for Shabbat (whether Shabbat is Yom Tov or not.)

Is someone allowed to roll a sefer Torah on Friday Yom Tov for using that Torah on Shabbat? Preparing the Torah in advance avoids *tircha detzibbur*. However, I understand that the eriv tavshilin only allows for food preparations, or would it also allow for something like prpearing the Torah as well? Or, is the avoidance of *tircha detzibbur*, for some reason a way of allowing this advanced preparation?

While, I don't know if this is a factor, here, but, say that there is no extra Torah available so that they can prepare one for Shabbat reading before Yom Tov begins. Would this situation make any difference in halacha?

Comment: I would suspect that it shouldn't be a problem. If not, there's always the alternative of going to schul early on Shabbos morning to set the sefer.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about Friday/Shabbos or any two-day yom tov?

Comment: @Daniel Specifically Friday/Shabbos. Otherwise there wouldn't be an Eruv Tavshilin.

Comment: DanF @NoachmiFrankfurt remember that there is no question you can roll it Fri night as that is already the next day.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I've heard in the name of R' Soloveitchik that one shouldn't prepare for Shabbos day during leil Shabbos

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt That's astounding.

Comment: One really has to know the purpose of eiruv tavshillin and how it works. Does it use "hoil" or not @DanF.   Does one eat it on the shabbos.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good thing that I asked my rav this evening, and he sent me [this](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/726345/rabbi-hershel-schachter/lesser-known-laws-of-torah-reading/#). It says:

> One may not shtel the Sefer on the first day of Yom Tov for the second
>   day, or on Shabbat for Yom Tov. Regarding preparing the Sefer on Yom
>   Tov for leinen on Shabbat, there are three opinions: Some forbid it
>   even if one has made an Eruv tavshilin; others only allow it in the
>   event that an Eruv tavshilin was made; and Rabbi Akiva Eger, whose
>   view is generally accepted, permits it even if one has not made an
>   Eruv tavshilin.

If I can discover more info as to the reasoning, esp. for Rav Akiva Eger's opinion, B"N, I'll edit this in.

Answer (score 1):

While there is a three way machlokes about rolling the sefer torah because of Hachana, Rav Shlomo Zalman Aurbach rules that he can do so if he is practicing the leining at the time that he rolls it.

[ROLLING THE TORAH](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/headlines-breaking-stories/408573/hachana-for-second-day-yom-tov.html)

> One may not roll a sefer Torah on first day Yom Tov for the reading on
>   second day Yom Tov (MB 667:5). When Yom Tov comes before Shabbos there
>   is a three-way debate as to rolling the Torah for Shabbos. Some forbid
>   it entirely, even with an Eiruv Tavshilin (MB in SH 667:7). Others
>   permit it with an Eiruv Tavshilin, and a third opinion seems to allow
>   it entirely (See Yom Tov k’Hilchaso p.399).
>
> Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach zt”l ruled that is permissible for a Baal
>   Koreh to prepare the leining on Yom Tov for the next day (cited in
>   Shmiras Shabbos K’hilchasa (28:178 note). The rationale is that his
>   knowledge is increased immediately and it is technically not just mere
>   hachana. This is in line with the principle that if there is benefit
>   that day as well, it is permitted even if the essential benefit is for
>   later (SSK 28:70)

Comment: Very good find. I'm putting up a related / follow-up question regarding this preparation for the current day concept.